# How can I print specific div area?

Tags: javascript, css, printing

I am adding print function (as a button) to my project. Specifically when user pressed "print" button , then user can print specific div area (not only div content) of calendar.

I tried following code but it is not printing the whole div area and the second problem is I can not do anything on browser after running this code(the page is dead).
It prints also only the div content by the way.

```
       on(dijit.byId("printCalendarButton"), "click", function(event) {
           var calendarContainer = dojo.byId("calendarContainer").innerHTML;   
           var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
           document.body.innerHTML = calendarContainer;
           window.print();
           document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
       });
```

I also tried with css,but it prints also only a part of the page:

```
@media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #calendarContainer * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  #calendarContainer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

Problem by printing:[image: Problem by printing image]

Is there any good Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Don't copy the content to the printable element, style the page so, that the elements to print are already marked in the markup. This resolves the dead page problem after printing (`document.body.innerHTML = calendarContainer;` recreates everything, but the events are not attached to the new elements). The partial visibility of the printed element might be due to the use of `visibility`. This property hides the elements, but they're still taking the their space on the layout. You could try `display: none` instead. Without a reproducible example it's hard to say anything more exact.

Comment: Thx.I have also tried `display: none` but unfortunately problem is still there.I attached the image of printing problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic printing arrangement you need for printing a single element with its content. Note specifically the CSS, when you're hiding all the elements inside the body with `body *`, this will also hide the elements to print.

To bring the printable elements to the print view, they all must be shown. This is made with `#printable, #printable * {display: block;}` rule. `#printable *` here is important, since the `body *` rule has hidden all the elements inside `body` by the type. Because types have a higher [specifity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance#specificity_2), we can't override that with any other selector.

To make the `body *` to work as intended, i.e. to hide everything on the page, there must not be orphanned textnodes in `body`, everything must be enclosed in elements.

```js
const but = document.querySelector('#printButton');
but.addEventListener('click', e => {
  window.focus();
  window.print();
});
```

```css
@media print {
  body * {
    display: none;
  }

  #printable, #printable * {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Some text visible on the screen only.</p>
<div id="printable">
  <p>This element is printed only (with its wrapper), but is visible also on the screen.</p>
</div>
<button id="printButton">Print</button>
<p>More text visible on the screen only.</p>
```

If the content shows up on the paper only partially, you've to scale it to fit to the paper, or split it over multiple pages. It's also possible, that the existing rules are defining margins and other stuff. If that's the case, you've to override such rules in the printing rules too. Media queries don't exclude existing rules, they're still applied, if not overridden.

You can play with [a demo at jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b94fr8uv/), it also shows how the orphanned textnodes are printed.

Comment: when I printing on Firefox,the scroll bar always automaticly scrolls to the top.As you can see in the pic,usually tickets starts from 6:00 or 7:00,but when printing it scrolls to 00:00.On Chrome is fine.Do you know what is the error?

Comment: I'd assume `window.focus()` is causing the scrolling in FF. You can omit that line, if there are no other windows on the page (iframes). I can't reproduce the issue with FF at the linked fiddle, though, maybe you should check, if your page has a focus handler which scrolls the page.

Comment: it is still scrolling without `window.focus()` :(

Comment: I've met a bit similar effects with FF when the size of the page is changed programmatically, but CSS for prints should not cause any effects on the screen layout. Such a scroll happens also at SO pages, when I return from a code snippet editing window back to the post page, it's annoying, and might be an issue (a bug) in FF itself.

Comment: i have tried your css and page misses some parts.So I have changed all `display` to `visibility`. It works not perfectly,but works better.when i scale the page to 70%,I can see the whole page.Still have a lot of works to do

Comment: Like said, this is only a "_basic arrangement_", it just introduces the idea, it has to be applied for individual pages. If the pringting layout doesn't work properly with `display`, then there are some screen CSS affecting the layout, you've to trace and override all those rules.